# How to troubleshoot the situation where XUnit tests fail with assertion of messages in NLog target under "Run All"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, nlog, xunit.net

### This is my environment:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Project's .NET runtime version is 4.6.2
- XUnit version 2.3.1
- NLog version 4.4.12
- Fluent Assertions 4.19.4

### This is the problem:

When I run the tests individually they pass, however when i run time via the "Run All" button in Test Explorer, I get failures and when repeating the running of the subsequent failed tasks, all of them pass eventually. Also want to point out that I am not running the tests in parallel. The nature of the tests are such that the code under test emits log information which eventually ends up in a custom NLog Target. Here is an example program which can be run in order to reproduce the problem.

```
using FluentAssertions;
using NLog;
using NLog.Common;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;
using Xunit;

namespace LoggingTests
{
    [Target("test-target")]
    public class TestTarget : TargetWithLayout
    {
        public ConcurrentBag<string> Messages = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        public TestTarget(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            Messages.Add(Layout.Render(logEvent));
        }
    }

    class Loggable
    {
        private Logger _logger;

        public Loggable()
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }

        private void Log(LogLevel level,
                         Exception exception,
                         string message,
                         params object[] parameters)
        {
            LogEventInfo log_event = new LogEventInfo();
            log_event.Level = level;
            log_event.Exception = exception;
            log_event.Message = message;
            log_event.Parameters = parameters;
            log_event.LoggerName = _logger.Name;
            _logger.Log(log_event);
        }

        public void Debug(string message)
        {
            Log(LogLevel.Debug,
                null,
                message,
                null);
        }

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            Log(LogLevel.Error,
                null,
                message,
                null);
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            Log(LogLevel.Info,
                null,
                message,
                null);
        }

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            Log(LogLevel.Fatal,
                null,
                message,
                null);
        }
    }

    public class Printer
    {
        public delegate void Print(string message);
        private Print _print_function;

        public Printer(Print print_function)
        {
            _print_function = print_function;
        }

        public void Run(string message_template,
                        int number_of_times)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_times; i++)
            {
                _print_function($"{message_template} - {i}");
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseTest
    {
        protected string _target_name;

        public BaseTest(LogLevel log_level)
        {
            if (LogManager.Configuration == null)
            {
                LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
                InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
                InternalLogger.LogFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                                      "nlog_debug.txt");
            }

            // Register target:
            _target_name = GetType().Name;
            Target.Register<TestTarget>(_target_name);

            // Create Target:
            TestTarget t = new TestTarget(_target_name);
            t.Layout = "${message}";

            // Add Target to configuration:
            LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(_target_name,
                                               t);

            // Add a logging rule pertaining to the above target:
            LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(log_level,
                                             log_level,
                                             t);

            // Because configuration has been modified programatically, we have to reconfigure all loggers:
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
        }
        protected void AssertTargetContains(string message)
        {
            TestTarget target = (TestTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName(_target_name);
            target.Messages.Should().Contain(message);
        }
    }

    public class TestA : BaseTest
    {
        public TestA() : base(LogLevel.Info)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            int number_of_times = 100;
            (new Printer((new Loggable()).Info)).Run(GetType().Name, 
                                                     number_of_times);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_times; i++)
            {
                AssertTargetContains($"{GetType().Name} - {i}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestB : BaseTest
    {
        public TestB() : base(LogLevel.Debug)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            int number_of_times = 100;
            (new Printer((new Loggable()).Debug)).Run(GetType().Name,
                                                     number_of_times);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_times; i++)
            {
                AssertTargetContains($"{GetType().Name} - {i}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestC : BaseTest
    {
        public TestC() : base(LogLevel.Error)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            int number_of_times = 100;
            (new Printer((new Loggable()).Error)).Run(GetType().Name,
                                                     number_of_times);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_times; i++)
            {
                AssertTargetContains($"{GetType().Name} - {i}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestD : BaseTest
    {
        public TestD() : base(LogLevel.Fatal)
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            int number_of_times = 100;
            (new Printer((new Loggable()).Fatal)).Run(GetType().Name,
                                                     number_of_times);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_times; i++)
            {
                AssertTargetContains($"{GetType().Name} - {i}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above test code runs better. After some earlier troubleshooting by following the messages, it appeared that I was not calling `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();` since the configurations are being created programatically (in the constructors of the test classes). Here is a note in the source code of `LogManager`:

```
/// Loops through all loggers previously returned by GetLogger.
/// and recalculates their target and filter list. Useful after modifying the configuration programmatically
/// to ensure that all loggers have been properly configured.
```

Afterwards all the tests ran as expected with occasional failures like shown below:

[image]

I am wondering now if there is anything more I should be securing in my test setup or is this rather a bug NLog. Any suggestion on how to go about to fix my test setup or, troubleshoot the setup would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

---

### Update

- Changed `List<LogData>` to `ConcurrentBag<LogData>`. This however does not change the problem. Problem remains that messages are not arriving into collection in a timely manner.
- Reformulated the problem and replaced previous code sample with an actual example (that can be run to reproduce the problem) + screenshots of the problem.
- Improved tests which run better but occasionally fail due to exceptions coming from NLog itself (added screenshot).

Comment: Could be a threading issue in the test with the shared resource. Try wrapping `Messages.Add` in a `lock`. I am certain that if each test had its own instance of the log target everything would work.

Comment: Even if I changed `List<LogData>` to `ConcurrentBag<LogData>` the problem remains: messages are not arriving into collection in a timely manner. I think i will resort to adding a trigger in the `Write()` method of the Target so as to eventually callback to the test method and run the assertions.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a StringWriter to NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogWriter and output the result using Console.WriteLine (Should be picked up by visual studio unit-test-runner)

Comment: I used `InternalLogger.LogFile` instead but could not track the failures such as exceptions thrown by NLog itself. However, my test setup has improved as described above.

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341259/nlog-custom-layoutrenderer-is-rendering-log-events-as-empty-string

Comment: Not a duplicate even if both posts look similar (style, about NLog, etc) and are by same author. The other one is about custom LayoutRenderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with above issue happens to be with XUnit Runner in VisualStudio. Eventhough i had 'DO NOT RUN TESTS IN PARALLEL' disabled, the tests were running in parallel somehow. @rolf-kristensen pointed in another NLog issue (Ref: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2525) that he had added the following:

```
[assembly: Xunit.CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```

in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. This configuration is also mentioned on XUnit's page (Ref: https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html - Changing Default Behavior)

Comment: This resolved my issue, but I was not using NLog in any dependent code, I was using TPL Dataflow.

Comment: The link to xunit.github.io is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Very random code you have shown, and very random details about what is failing. So maybe my suggestions doesn't make sense to your problem.

Instead of calling `TestLogTarget` directly, then you should setup a logging configuration:

```
var target = new TestLogTarget() { Name = "Test" };
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator(target);
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("Hello World");
```

Make sure to add a `lock` around the access to the Messages. Either by making a `ToArray()` while holding the `lock` (or calling `Contains` while holding the `lock`)

Remember that NLog is a global engine, which require special effort in a unit testing environment where test-classes, test-appdomains are stopped and started frequently, so you need to know your unit-test-system and your nlog-system to make them work together.

Comment: Even if I changed `List<LogData>` to `ConcurrentBag<LogData>` the problem remains: messages are not arriving into collection in a timely manner. I think i will resort to adding a trigger in the `Write()` method of the Target so as to eventually callback to the test method and run the assertions. Sorry if I was not clear, however in terms of what is failing: it is assertions on the existence of a given log message in the (data-structure Messages) which is suppose to hold all the log messages. Also i am registering the Target via SimpleConfigurator like you are doing above (ref: constructor)

Comment: I have reformulated the problem and added code which can be run (have to install dependencies: `XUnit`, `FluentAssertions` and `NLog`) in order to reproduce the problem (see newly added screenshots in the problem description).

Comment: Well the NLog project is using xUnit, and is doing nothing but logging, and validating that logging is correct.

Comment: I had a look at the NLog tests on the github and I am not able to get to the same kind of setup. Example, all tests inherit from `NLogTestBase` and in its constructor, `Close()` is called on `LogManager.Configuration`. However, there is no `Close()` method on `LoggingConfiguration`.

Comment: It is the same as calling `LogManager.Configuration = null;`